# How to trigger console app on Linux from Java app

Tags: java, linux, console-application

I have console app in Ubuntu that receives as input just letter `"a"`.

So when user types `"a"` in console - this triggers some other process.

Now I have Java app that would need to trigger this console app by passing `"a"` to it.

What would be best way to implement that? I just need few pointers.

Tried to find similar soulutons but no luck.

Comment: I hope you have a script and "a" is just an argument to the script?

Comment: @learner could be bult like that. That's not a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
package stackoverflow;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class ProcessAccess {



    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
        final Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(args);

        // write text to os
        final OutputStream os = process.getOutputStream();
        os.write("a".getBytes());

        // maybe needs newline to simulate enter key, \n may be enough for windows
        // use any of the following 2
        final String lineSeparator1 = System.lineSeparator();
        final String lineSeparator2 = System.getProperty("line.separator");

        os.write(lineSeparator1.getBytes());

        os.flush(); // may not be needed, check out process.getOutputStream()'s documentation


        // quick and dirty reading of app output, you can do that a lot better
        final InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
        while (true) {
            final int b = is.read();
            if (b == -1) break;

            System.out.print((char) b);
        }

        // same quick+dirty. remember you might need to use multi-threading or pseudo-parallel read if you depend on output of either in or err channel
        final InputStream es = process.getErrorStream();
        while (true) {
            final int b = es.read();
            if (b == -1) break;

            System.out.print((char) b);
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: This console app runs on Linux. So were do I enter it's proccess name in your solution? It is here - `final Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(args);`

Comment: Yes, you can write `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("htop");` or `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/path/to/app -test");` or `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/path/to/app", "-test");` for example. In my example, I simply forward the command line arguments that the .jar / java app was started with, to the target app. So `java -jar ProcessAccess.jar /path/to/app -param1 -param2 etc` becomes `/path/to/app -param1 -param2 etc`.

Comment: I'm able to run client app through Java based on your example, and it seems that it works ok but after typing command ("a") nothing happens. Any ideas?

Comment: 1) Maybe you have to wait until the app is started and actually waits for the input. Read the `in` channel until the app has printed the prompt for entering the input, then write 'a' (and probably a lineSeparator) to the app. 2) Did you catch the output? 3) Maybe your method (the one I posted) finishes before the app returns any data. So read _in_ and _err_ in a (pseudo) multithreaded way, and in total wait until the app has reacted or finished (read in or err or use `process.waitFor()`) 4) for further details you should open another question and give A LOT MORE details, ...

Comment: ESPECIALLY details on the app you're trying to control.